# PHP Checking if a numbered string follows a pattern

Tags: php

I am comparing inputs of different version numbers looking like so:

```
testname-v01.03.001.01
testname-v02.01.001.03
...
```

I am doing a comparison to make sure that no inputs are being maliciously entered into my textbook to harm my sql tables.

What I am doing is something like this:

```
<?php
    function startsWith($needle, $haystack){
        return $needle === "" || strrpos($haystack, $needle, -strlen($haystack)) !== false;
    }
    $reqmethod = $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];
    $textInput = "";
    if( $reqmethod == "GET") {
        $textInput = $_GET["my_input"];
    }
    $stringComparison = "v02.01.001.01";
    if ( $textInput != ""){
        $valid_input = startsWith("testname", $textInput); #See if text starts with version
        #if not check if its a partial match
        if (!$valid_input){
            if(preg_match('/^[A-Z][0-9]+.[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]', $textInput)){
            $textInput= "version-" + $textInput;
        } else {
            $textInputReadOut = "BAD VALUE";
            $textInput= "";
        }
    }
?>
```

To get the `preg_match` to equal say `v01` would I just go about that by doing something like this: `[A-Z][0-9][0-9]`? I have tried that but the variable returns a **BAD VALUE** instead

Referenced : [Checking a string against a pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737091/checking-a-string-against-a-pattern)

Comment: It's always good to validate that your input matches an expected pattern or value, but this is not generally the way you want to rely on protecting yourself from SQL injection. You should use prepared statements with bound parameters, via either [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). [**This post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has some good examples.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at your regex:

`if(preg_match('/^[A-Z][0-9]+.[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]', $textInput)){`

you are missing the closing `/`

It has to be:

`if(preg_match('/^[A-Z][0-9]+.[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]/', $textInput)){`

**And here the corrected version:**

`^[a-zA-Z][0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{2}`

You can use tools like **[regexr](https://regexr.com/3s32o)** to test your regex.

Comment: Thank you for the advice on the regexr, but I read more about the comment that @Alex Howansky made earlier and I am going to follow that path since it seems to be better for protecting from SQL Injections

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression is matching strings that *start with* (`^`) v1.2.3.4, but your `$textInput` starts with `testname` (or presumably other package names).

You also have it coded that the regular expression only checks if the input is *invalid*. Your text input is always valid, because it always starts with testname, meaning you always land in your `else` wherein the output is `BAD VALUE`. Any time your `$textInput` starts with `testname`, the output is `BAD VALUE`, as far as your code is currently concerned.